# Can the docking components in the JEDI Visual Component Library be used to help program 10 scrolling text windows

Tags: delphi-xe2, jedi, jvcl

I would like add 10 dockable windows to a Delphi XE2 application.  Each window will display lines of text received from a network of external sensors, with a different window for each sensor.

Information on these pages and elsewhere indicates that the JEDI Visual Component Library may have some nice components to help with this.

Specifically, I found this documentation:

> Jv Docking
>
> Docking Server and DockingStyle components. Docking looks identical to standard delphi docking (no docking indicators while dragging), only the captions of the docked windows are changed according to the styles.

Does the JEDI Visual Component Library have components that could ease the job of programming 10 dockable scrolling text windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JvDocking` controls allow easy docking of windows; those windows can contain anything you'd like them to, including Delphi's standard `TScrollBox`. The JVCL has some scrollable panels as well.

If you have questions about what's in the JVCL library, the best thing to do is download it and look at the files it contains. You can do that without installing it if you download the manual installation (zip) file.

Note that the main problem with the JEDI libraries are that they lack documentation for most components (or functions, in the JEDI code library), so you'll need to be good at reading component and (limited) demo source files. There are also a *lot* of components included, including many that duplicate functionality; it's often hard to find the minor differences between them, and many come with no documentation or demo.